# Как обновить dataGridView в C#, не закрывая форму?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!

Если кто сталкивался с этим, подскажите, как обновить `dataGridView`, не закрывая форму. Вот код программы. Пользователь вводит название в текстовое поле, нажимает кнопку **Browse** и выбирате изображение. Нажимает кнопку **Add** и все это добавляет в базу данных. Чтобы отобразились данные в `dataGridView`, нужно сперва закрыть форму, затем открыть. Как сделать так, чтобы форму не закрывать, а нажать на кнопку **Refresh** и данные, только что введенные, отобразились в `dataGridView`. `dataGridView1.Refresh()` и `dataGridView1.Update()` не обновляют данные. Подскажите.

Вот код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  string pathImageBrand = string.Empty;
  public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();
  }
  //кнопка Browse
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.ico; *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.ico; *.png";
   if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    pathImageBrand = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
   }
  }
  //кнопка Add
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string stringConnect = @"server=localhost;user id=root;password=12345;database=abc";
   string sql = "INSERT INTO avto VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"', @imgBrands)";

   byte[] imgBrands = null;
   FileStream fsBrand = new FileStream(pathImageBrand, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   BinaryReader brBrand = new BinaryReader(fsBrand);
   imgBrands = brBrand.ReadBytes((int)fsBrand.Length);

   using(MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(stringConnect)) {
    connect.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connect);
    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@imgBrands", imgBrands));
    int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + "record(s) saved");
   }
   textBox1.Clear();
  }
  //кнопка Refresh
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //обновить таблицу не закрывая, а затем открывая форму
   //dataGridView1.Update();
   dataGridView1.Refresh();
  }
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'abcDataSet.avto' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
   this.avtoTableAdapter.Fill(this.abcDataSet.avto);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Вы читаете базу в `Button_Click`? И ещё никто не пожаловался, что у вас программа подвисает?

Comment: @Anton121212, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Где Вы тут видите исчерпывающий ответ? Его тут нет, сплошное ля-ля...

Comment: //кнопка Refresh
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 //обновить таблицу не закрывая, а затем открывая форму
 this.avtoTableAdapter.Fill(this.abcDataSet.avto);
}

Answer (score 1):

А Вы хотите, чтобы данные в `abcDataSet.avto` каким-то чудом сами попали? В обработчике `button2_Click` Вы выполняете добавление напрямую в базу, а `abcDataSet.avto` после этого не обновляете. Раз уж начали пользоваться `SqlDataAdapter`, то с помощью его и выполняйте всё взаимодействие с БД. А если хотите оставить как есть, то после добавления данных в БД обновляйте `abcDataSet.avto` руками.

Answer (score 0):

Повторно загружайте данные.

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае, из главной формы вызывалось новое окно, для добавления данных в базу MS SQL, но после добавления и закрытия вспомогательного окна DataGridView сам не обновлялся...
Потратил несколько часов на поиски решения, и сильно удивился когда нашел гениальное решение обновление DataSet.
Пример обновления прилагаю -

> ```
> private void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         this.clientsTableAdapter.Fill(this.onlineStoreDataSet.Clients);
>     }
> ```